# Worklight Server 6.2 JMS Adapter javax/jms/ExceptionListener

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mobilefirst, activemq-classic

I'm trying to use a JMS Adapter in a Worklight 6.2 project based on this tutorial (WL + ActiveMQ):

http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/04_05_JMS_adapter_-_Communicating_with_JMS.pdf.

When I deploy the adapter into the WL Server, it fails and the server returns the following error:

"Adapter deployment failed: RuntimeException:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/ExceptionListener"

So, I provide the following jars into the server/libs:

- activemq-core-5.7.0.jar
- javax.jms-1.1.jar

but unfortunately the result is the same.

Can you have any suggestion to resolve this problem?

Many thanks,
Stefano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have an activemq-all-activemq_version_number.jar file. Put this file in the server\lib directory and try again.

Comment: thanks, it works. additionally, i found this IBM doc that describes the solution that you have provided: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/server-side-development/jms-adapter-communicating-jms/
Regards